# AWS CloudFront - redirect root domain requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lambda

First time poster on serverfault, apologies if this is in the wrong place. I have a website that I am trying to set up on AWS CloudFront. It is currently configured to serve static web content from S3, this is then picked up and served via CloudFront. However, I want all of the requests for rootdomain.com to go to rootdomain.com/blog - and the rest of the requests for that domain to be handled as normal.

From my Googling so far, this seems like something that I could achieve using lambda@edge. However, all of my attempts so far have been unsuccessful.

How do I go about configuring lambda/cf/s3 to achieve what I have laid out above?

Apologies if I have missed anything, thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want `/` redirected to `/blog` you can do a simple `index.html` based redirect. *Lambda@Edge* is a very powerful mechanism but very much an overkill for your usecase.

To use `index.html` for the redirect do this:

1. **[Configure the S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) for website hosting**, that will also make sure that a request to `/` will serve the contents of `/index.html`.
2. **Create and upload the `/index.html` file** with a content like this:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Redirect to /blog</title>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/blog" />
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Now every time a request is made to `http://rootdomain.com/` the browser will receive the above HTML file and follow the refresh/redirect to `http://rootdomain.com/blog`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your response :) This was perfect and resolved the issue for me. Not sure why I didn't think of this in the first place! Think I got a bit carried away playing with AWS. Cheers!